# jQuery form validation for password strength

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a little bit confusion regarding a jquery validation, in my below password validation, only 1 error condition is working, if i comment 1 condition then the other 1 is working great, but both are not working, means the 1st one not working but second is working. How to make both of them working as both having different output.

```
<script>
            //Password validation for blank and strong only
            jQuery("#password").blur(function() {
            var password = document.getElementById('fullname').value;

            checkStrength($('#password').val());
            });

            function checkStrength(password){
                //initial strength
                var strength = 0;

                //if the password length is 0, return message. 
                if (password.length == 0) { 
                    $('#pmessage').html('Password cannot be blank.').css('color', 'red');
                }
                else { 
                    $('#pmessage').html('');
                }

                //if the password length is less than 6, return message. 
                if ((password.length > 0) && (password.length < 6)) {
                    $('#pmessage').html('Too short.').css('color', 'red');
                }
                else { 
                    $('#pmessage').html('');
                }

            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You are overwriting the complete HTML content of the same element, so yeah, of course you only see the last message this script has output. Either gather the messages in an array and set that as content at the end, or append to the current HTML content of the element, instead of replacing it.

Comment: @RanaPratap Your code is correct only need to check `password.length != 0`  in second condition. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `append` instead of `html`. See the code

```
<script>
    jQuery("#password").blur(function() {
        var password = document.getElementById('fullname').value;

        checkStrength($('#password').val());
    });

    function checkStrength(password){
        //initial strength
        var strength = 0;
        $('#pmessage').html('').css('color', 'red');
        //if the password length is 0, return message. 
        if (password.length == 0) {
            $('#pmessage').append('<div>Password cannot be blank.</div>');
        }

        //if the password length is less than 6, return message. 
        if ((password.length > 0) && (password.length < 6)) {
            $('#pmessage').append('<div>Too short.</div>');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `password.length != 0` in second condition.

```js
//Password validation for blank and strong only
jQuery("#password").blur(function() {
  checkStrength($('#password').val());
});

function checkStrength(password) {
  //initial strength
  var strength = 0;
  //if the password length is 0, return message. 
  if (password.length === 0) {
    $('#pmessage').html('Password cannot be blank.').css('color', 'red');
  } else {

    $('#pmessage').html('');
  }
  //if the password length is less than 6, return message. 
  if ((password.length > 0) && (password.length < 6)) {

    $('#pmessage').html('Too short.').css('color', 'red');
  } else {
    if (password.length != 0)
      $('#pmessage').html('');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='password' />
<label id='pmessage'></label>
```